# Creating a variable from a certain line while reading a file

Tags: java

I am working on a short code that is supposed to read through a file and recognize the second line of code, and assign it to a variable to print out to the console. However I am issues getting the variable to either set or to set to the correct string. The first few times I tried it, I was receiving the third line as my String variable. After a few tweaks to the code, I am now receiving null as the return value for my variable. My code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class A9 {
    
    public static String readSecondLine(String path) {
        File newfile = new File(path);
        String lineTwo = null;
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newfile))) {
            while((lineTwo = br.readLine()) != null) {
                br.readLine();
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    if(i == 1) {
                        lineTwo = br.readLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lineTwo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/src/newtext.txt";
        System.out.println(readSecondLine(path));
    }
    
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please step through your code with the debugger. Given the exit condition of your while loop, what value do you think `lineTwo` can have after the loop?

Comment: The problem is that for every line you read, you're trying to read 2 more lines. You're skipping the 2nd line and you only care about the third one. The output is going to depend on the amount of lines in your file. 

What you need to do is be able to distinguish lines from each other based on some criteria. This could be the line content itself, or maybe the number of the corresponding line using an ordered collection.

Comment: Yes that's right, skipping is occurring. I imagine the processing is badly explained, and what is meant is actually, rather than "the second line", what is intended is to read *all* even-numbered lines. Why, I don't know. It might be useful to post the input file.
In addition to the `for` loop making little sense, you cannot be certain that any of the `nextLine` calls other than the one invoked in the `while` statement is legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use java stream api and **skip()** method to skip first n lines of the file.

```
  public static String readSecondLine(String path) {
    File newfile = new File(path);
    String lineTwo = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newfile))) {
        lineTwo = br.lines().skip(1).findFirst().orElse("There were no second line in file");
    }  catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lineTwo;
}
```